# Openshift SSH quota?

Tags: ssh, openshift-online-2

I am using SSH to access to Openshift VM, i'm running a simple java program (java -jar ....) that takes a while a to complete, and do some heavy work.
But the execution always gets terminated, along with the SSH session.
Using putty, i get a

> Server unexpectedly closed network connection

I have tried to set the TMOUT variable to a higher value, and enabled the TCP keepalives from putty. It works when idle, but when i run the java program it get excluded once again after like 5min.

So are there any restriction or limits set by openshift?
any other configuration i can do to fix this?
and how can i can the last exiting error in java or the ssh session?

**EDIT:**
I alos tried lunching it with:
nohup java -jar name.jar &

and it also died after several minutes (i checked using ftp logs)

Comment: What Do The Logs Say?

Comment: @JennyD if ur talking about the ftp logs, im just looking at the last modified date of the nohup.out file, other than that, i dont know which logs i should be looking at

Comment: Maybe it's getting killed because the machines runs out of memory...?

Comment: Whyever would ftp logs be relevant to a process dying and an SSH session getting closed down? You need to check the server's system logs.

Comment: @JennyD cuz when i use nohup, the process continue working even if the ssh session is terminated? and im using openshift, its a shared environment, i dont know where i can find the logs, or if i have access to them.

Comment: @JennyD would you mind telling me why you marked the question as off-topic?

Comment: @OuerghiYassine For the reason stated in the close message. What part of it is unclear?

Comment: The part where it said "off-topic", according to [serverfault help](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic), is stated: `tools used for administering, monitoring, or automating these`, which i think what my question is about, also `deployment to and management of third-party provided information technology platforms`, what openshift is.

Answer (score 3):

You should not be relying on keeping an SSH connection active for successful execution of a long-running process. Instead of doing is as you are, start up a tmux or GNU screen session first and run your process within that. This way, the process will continue running if your SSH connection dies.

Comment: ...and if the connection dies because reasons, there might be remnants in the screen/tmux session that tell you what happened.

Comment: yes, sorry forgot to mention i even tried "nohup java -jar name.jar &" it died after some mins (checked through ftp logs)